# NSDateFormatter return blank for minute if == 0

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

The code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"m"];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:myDate]);
```

outputs: `0` if `myDate` has its minute value to `0`.

This is normal, but **how do I make it output a blank value** instead of `0` if the minute is set to `0`?

Comment: What do you mean by a blank value? `" "` or `""`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSString * newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0" withString:@""];`

Comment: This works, but does `NSDateFormatter` have any settings to automatically set it to ""?